# Django Safari Iframe Issue

Tags: python, django, iframe, safari

We have shopify app in django that is embedded in shopify. But this app is facing issues as an iframe in Safari Browser. I have referenced this doc https://pypi.org/project/django-iframetoolbox/ . But I didnt understand the order in which I have to include this in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
    'shopify_app.middleware.LoginProtection',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'iframetoolbox.middleware.IFrameFixMiddleware',
]
```

This is the current order in which I have given and this is giving me the following error:

raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'shopify_django_app.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.

Comment: I don't think that's your problem... The error is pointing to `shopify_app`. Is that your local project/app name or another app you installed?

Comment: That is a local app/project name